# How to merge csv data into datagridview without distrubing existing data

Tags: vb.net

I have a small csv data file with 7 columns and initially 6 rows.  The first column is a ranking (1-6). The second column is a key. the remaining columns identify properties of the key...size, weight, color etc.  I  display the first csv file in a datagridview control. One week later I append the datagridview display by adding new ranking data into column 8 from a new csv file which has the same items with the same keys (not in the same order) that were in the first csv file (column2). However, this second csv file has an additional item that might be any row of the new scv file. It should be put in row 7 of the datagridview with its new key (for column 2) and its associated values of size, weight, color etc. for the other columns.

My problem is: how do I add the new item (row7) to the datagridview control with its new key and associated properties without distrubing the data already displayed on the datagridview ?

The code below works for updating the same items with their keys but it does not add the new item with its new key and associated data. The first code list is for loading the first csv file

```
Using MR As New TextFieldParser(newFile)
        Dim currentRow As String()
        MR.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MR.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        While Not MR.EndOfData
            Try
                Dgv1.Rows.Add()
                currentRow = MR.ReadFields()
                Dgv1(1, rd).Value = currentRow(1)
                Dgv1(2, rd).Value = currentRow(2)
                Dgv1(3, rd).Value = currentRow(3)
                Dgv1(4, rd).Value = currentRow(4)
                Dgv1(5, rd).Value = currentRow(5)
                Dgv1(6, rd).Value = currentRow(0)
                rd += 1
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End While
    End Using
```

Update button code

```
Using MR As New TextFieldParser(newFile)
        Dim currentRow As String()
        MR.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MR.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        While Not MR.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MR.ReadFields()
                For re = 0 To Dgv1.RowCount - 1
                    If Dgv1(1, re).Value = currentRow(1) Then
                        Dgv1(7, re).Value = currentRow(0)
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
```

Comment: Can you add an image of your datagridview for a bit more clarity.

Comment: I would be happy to add an image and perhaps more clarity but I am not sure how I do that via Stack Overflow. It would be nice if I had your email address so I could send to you directly.   Ed